# Not sure if putting rewrite rule in httpd.conf is correct

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make sure if I go to this url:

http://www.mydomain.com/bob

I get taken to

http://www.mydomain.com/bob/

I know I could create a php file called bob.php which redirects to the folder /bob/ however I want to learn to do this with an apache rewrite rule.

I have tried the following rule:

RewriteRule ^bob$ /bob/ [L]

and put this in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

however this doesn't seem to work. Any pointers as to what is wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Is there a real folder called bob? is there a file called bob or anything. Are you just wanting a trailing slash... if so look here  http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/trailing-slash/